# Mixing code with i18n and without it

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, gettext

I have a running website that I've made for my customer. It works in two languages: English and Polish. The texts in the code are in English and Polish translation is done by standard gettext.

Now my customer ordered another website where a lot of code from the first one can be reused. However, the new website is directed more to local market and will be in Polish with very likely translation to English in the future.

Of course I have all texts for the new site in Polish and I'm not getting paid for translating it to English.

The question is: how should I proceed to make things work and save me the effort in case the new site will be translated to English?

The most lazy approach would be:

1. Don't touch old texts.
2. Write new texts in Polish, having a mix of both languages in the code.
3. Once English translation is ready translate these in *.po* files

This would be simple but resulting in horrible mess and make eventual translations even harder (e.g. someone preparing German would have to translate from both Polish and English).

Any better ways to do it and save myself from manual replacement of all new texts when customer orders the translation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not very far from the best approach using the lazy one:

1. Don't touch old texts.
2. **Don't write new texts in Polish, use some placeholders instead. Let placeholder best describe what text is, i.e. *page_title*.**
3. Once English translation is ready you can translate these in .po files, but it may make sense to replace placeholders with English text. Actually when you have .po file with English translations it is a just a matter of simple script.

That's it. Of course this approach can make things a bit tricky when you want to add a new language, especially if you don't have English translation yet. But, I believe it could still be manageable (although this depends on the code base size).